# java.lang.IllegalStateException while creating alert dialog in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception

A beginner here..

I'm unable to create alert dialog. It occurs when I use `alertDialog.show();

this error--

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

my code,

```
 logoImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setTitle("hello");
            builder.setMessage("hello how are you");
            AlertDialog alertDialog= builder.create();
            alertDialog.show(); //line 


        }

    });
```

my logcat..

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:94)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:279)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:283)
    at com.abmm.include_activity$15.onClick(include_activity.java:459)
```

thank you buddies..

Comment: possible duplicate 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: @Ashishsingh I read this did not help me.. also I'm not finding any explanation about what they are doing and why?

Comment: @Monk in your activity class from where you are calling dialog ,extend from Activity instead of AppcompatActivity .

Comment: its done buddy @Ashishsingh

its the error of context.. I declared the context globally Context mycontext=this; and then AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mycontext);

thanks for ur support ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: `this` won't work since the Alert is inside a click listener. Make a reference to the activity context instead.

Comment: if you are calling this from activity than pass that context like, MainActivity.this or if this is fragment than getActivity()

Comment: Hi @Zun I tried it like AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(include_Activity.this); 

Same error is giving..
please help

Comment: @HardikChauhan hiii......I have done this buddy , dont know why its giving same error..help pls

Comment: are you calling this dialog from activity or fragment?

Comment: what theme you are using in your manifest file?

Comment: @HardikChauhan from activity..i dont have any fragment

Comment: @HardikChauhan its done... I declared Context mycontext= this; in the top of class and then AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mycontext);

it solved the error..thanks for ur support too...